# TypeError: AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I try to use Amazons DocumentClient for AWS.dynamodb from the aws-sdk. I also use the Standard node.js VM from Amazon: "64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v4.0.1 running Node.js".

On my local machine everything is working fine, but I get the following error message live:

```
TypeError: AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient is not a constructor
```

And this is the line causing the error:

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

I also tried different versions which are used by various tutorials which also fail:

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: "eu-central-1"});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
```

I tried to follow this guide very precisely:
https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/developer/announcing-the-amazon-dynamodb-document-client-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript/

On my local machine it works without a problem. I can connect to the live server or the local dev-server without errors.

AWS.dynamodb without the DocumentClient was also working on the live server, so I guess one option would be to drop DocumentClient alltogether.

I have a package.json which uses the latest aws-sdk:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "latest",
[...]
```

My best guess is, that something is wrong with the node packages. How do I check my assumption and if right, change something about it?

Comment: Mine is `"aws-sdk": "^2.2.15"` and `new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()` works. Also, check if you have `const AWS = require('aws-sdk')` in the file.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer!

I do have the line `const AWS = require('aws-sdk')`.

I managed to break my local setup after running `npm install` and now get the same error, at least I can now try fixing it there. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution! @SwarajGiri pointed in the right direction by suggesting aws-sdk version 2.2.15.

My problem was that I had a [npm-shrinkwrap.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) in my folder and was not aware that it was overruling the package.json. The aws-sdk version inside the npm-shrinkwrap.json was 2.1.39 which does not include the documentClient(). [Document Client was introduced in version 2.2.0](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/developer/announcing-the-amazon-dynamodb-document-client-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript/)

Note that the [node.js Elastic Beantalk with DynamoDB tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-dynamodb-tutorial.html) I followed includes this somewhat outdated npm-shrinkwrap.json!

I hope I do not break any rules by answering my own question.